# Asp.net Core 2.0 View Localization Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Hi tried to do localization in .net core 2.0
I followed this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization
Visual Studio 2017
Windows 10

After adding these files in Resources(for view Index) and compiling

[See Resource Files I Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1u4I.png)

I get his error on build

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' attribute    Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en-US.Designer.cs 22  Active
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute' attribute   Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en-US.Designer.cs 23  Active
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute' attribute    Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en-US.Designer.cs 24  Active
Error   CS0101  The namespace 'Mnp.Resources.Views.Home' already contains a definition for 'Index'  Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en-US.Designer.cs 25  Active
Error   CS0111  Type 'Index' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types  Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en-US.Designer.cs 32  Active
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' attribute    Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en.Designer.cs    22  Active
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute' attribute   Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en.Designer.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute' attribute    Mnp E:\Websites\Developing\Mnp\Mnp\BudgetT\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en.Designer.cs    24  Active
```

[See the Duplicate Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8p6h.png)

Am I adding the files wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core localization, you do not need the the .Designer.cs files.

For each of the resource files, select the file in the solution explorer and then hit F4 to view its properties. Select the value specified as "Custom Tool" and delete it.

The field "Custom Tool" should be empty.

[image]

Even if you did need the code generated by the custom tool, you would only require it on one of the files (typically the neutral language .resx file).

In your screen shot, I can see that you have the files:

- Index.en.Designer.cs
- Index.en-IN.Designer.cs
- Index.en-US.Designer.cs

These three files will contain duplicate code, which is causing the compilation errors.